# External javascript reference in html tag

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a problem with placing an external javascript reference inside html tags? An advertiser of mine has placed an external javascript reference in a stack of divs so that a third party can track users of the website. The third party is unable to track the users because the JS reference is in a "container" tag and the "pixel" is not firing in their UI. My main question is if it makes sense that the referenced js would not load because of where it is placed within the html doc. When I look at the source, it looks like the external js loaded.

e.g

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
        <script async src="https://tag.simpli.fi/sifitag/f8386e60-0805-0135-53dd-0cc47a63c1a4"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the problem may be in the path

Comment: 1. that you're missing the closing `</script>` 2. That the DOM parsing will be paused for JS interpretation

Comment: what is the problem you are seeing?

Comment: I should have included more info. The live example is written as such: <script async src="https://tag.simpli.fi/sifitag/f8386e60-0805-0135-53dd-0cc47a63c1a4"></script>  The script is not allowing a third party to track when the script is loaded.

Comment: You need to provide a real [mcve] and **tell us what the problem is**

Comment: @amdilger If the question is incomplete, edit the question to add the details, don't put them in comments.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console related to this script?

Comment: @barmar   I will edit the question with the full details. I am not receiving any errors in the js console related to the specified external js call.

Answer (score 2):

This forces your browser to stop processing the HTML, immediately download, and execute the JavaScript before continuing.  It's an inefficient way to deal with scripts.

If this script relies on this behavior, it probably isn't following best practices by using `document.write()` and such.

Also don't forget that script tags need a closing `</script>`.

Comment: I should have included more info. The live example is written as such: <script async src="https://tag.simpli.fi/sifitag/f8386e60-0805-0135-53dd-0cc47a63c1a4"></script>  The script is not allowing a third party to track when the script is loaded.

Comment: @amdilger Whatever it is that you're asking... write a new question.  And, include as much info as possible.  Your comment doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @amdilger Make a new question.